# Automatically update analysis without manually refreshing or changing tab

Tags: refresh, amazon-quicksight

Within our analysis, we have multiple tabs. Each tab contains a number of graphs. Currently, new data is only added to the graphs when we change the tab, and the graph is reloaded, or when a user manually selects the refresh option. Is there an option within Quicksight that allows graphs to be automatically updated at set intervals, say each 1 minute, when using direct query datasets?

Answer (score 0):

When you are publishing analysis to a dashboard, click "Advanced publish options" in the dialog and look for "Enable auto-refresh for visualizations"

I believe at the moment this option is only available for dashboards that use direct query datasets, not datasets ingested into SPICE.

If you have more questions, this thread should be useful https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/auto-dashboard-page-refresh/589/5